# Linux kernel process execution with logging all IO

Tags: kernel, security, logs, system-calls

Is there option to have sort of proxy on executing binary file, that reads and handles all it's syscalls? I know it's KVM, but I need to access this data on what application is doing, is there open source tool like that?

Comment: If you need only to catch syscalls input or output data (arguments and results), `strace(1)` is pretty enough, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it's quite good, but I've haven't heard of it before, thank you.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/draios/sysdig/ as well